# Automatically create dropdown with EditorForModel()

Tags: c#-4.0, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a model with a
`public IEnumerable<SelectListItem> Selections {get;set;}` and one `public string SelectedItem {get;set;}`, how can I override the default behavior in asp.net mvc so it renders a dropdown for this property? I have a generic edit ui so I can't do things like `Html.DropDownListFor(...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at custom templates: http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-4-custom-object-templates.html

Comment: Worked pretty nice, it seems like the validation of the model breaks, ModelState.IsValid is true but UpdateModel fails because I have left some fields in my child model empty when they are required